# Do Lands count as permanents? Did I find a bug in Magic Arena?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-arena

I played a match with [Chromatic Orrery](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChromatic%20Orrery%5d) on the battlefield.
I had no creatures, no enchantments or anything else on the field but around 10 Lands of 7 different types. 7 mixed and 2 single colors and one radiant fountain
I activated the ability of Chromatic Orrery "Draw a card for each color among permanents you control"
Nothing happened.

Are Lands colorless, not permanent or is this a bug?

Comment: It's confusing because lands are the only colorless permanents they still use colored borders for - but they base that on the colors the lands make, not the colors they are - lands have no color.

Answer (score 7):

**Lands are colorless permanents, so they will not cause you to draw any cards with Chromatic Orrery.**

This is a result of [rule 202.2](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Mana_cost):

> **202.2.** An object is the color or colors of the mana symbols in its mana cost, regardless of the color of its frame.

> - **202.2b** Objects with no colored mana symbols in their mana costs are colorless.

Lands have no mana cost, so they have no colored symbols in their mana cost, so they are colorless.

Comment: As always, the exception: Dryad Arbor has a green color indicator and is thus green.

Comment: Animated man-lands tend to have colors, with a few exceptions like Mutavault.